# Do have way to change framework of DirectX 9 from .NET 2 to .NET 4

Tags: directx, nvidia

I'm beginner in DirectX. I found source to active NVIDIA 3d Stereo in DirectX 9, but the DirectX9 don't support .NET 4 and all my project and dll files writen in .NET 4 C#. Is there any way to change framework of DirectX 9 ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751179/managed-directx-running-from-net-framework-4-0-app-dont-hunt

Answer (score 0):

The 3D Stereo source is using Managed DirectX (MDX) right? Pitifully, MDX is not supported now, it can be used only in .Net 1.1 ~ 2.0. As it is closed sources of Microsoft, it cannot be  changed to have compatibility with .Net 4.0.

But there are projects for replacing MDX like SharpDX. SharpDX is recently providing .Net 4.0 bindings. http://sharpdx.org/news/sharpdx-july2012-status It has all features of MDX. It will work if you change interfaces of the 3D Stereo source to be connected with SharpDX instead of MDX.