# Why when running new project it's not showing any windows and break points never work it's never get to the form1 constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I had this problem on my first project so i tried now to make a new project but i had the same problem so i did the test in form1 constructor and found that something is wrong with the DopplerEffect class.

I did a test now. This is my original Form1 code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DopplerRadar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DopplerEffect de = new DopplerEffect();
            de.pb1 = pictureBox1;
            de.bmpWithPoints = new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\anim3.gif");
            de.numberOfPoints = 100;
            de.randomPointsColors = false;
            de.Init();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i put a break point on the line:

```
DopplerEffect de = new DopplerEffect();
```

It will never stop on it.

But if i move all the code from the Form1 and just adding for the test one line:

```
string tt = "tt";
```

And then put a break point on this line it will stop on the line.

So i guess the problem is somewhere with the class DopplerEffect.

But if i put also a break point on the DopplerEffect code it's not stopping there either.

So the problem is with the DopplerEffect but i can't figure out why and where.

This is the DopplerEffect code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace DopplerRadar
{
    public class DopplerEffect
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private Stream mymem;
        private Bitmap ConvertedBmp;
        private Device D3Ddev = null;
        private PresentParameters D3Dpp = null;
        private DisplayMode DispMode;
        private Sprite D3Dsprite = null;
        private Texture backTexture = null;
        private Texture scannedCloudsTexture = null;
        private byte[] argbValuesOfTransparentTexture;
        private float distanceFromCenterPixels;
        private float distanceFromCenterKm = 200F;
        private List<Point> detectedPoints;
        private float[] angleArray, distanceArray;
        private double angleCalculation, distance;
        private int bytes = 2048 * 512;
        private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        private Random r = new Random();
        private Bitmap bmpnew;
        private Bitmap bmpWithoutPoints;

        public int numberOfPoints = 100;
        public Color pointsColor = Color.Red;
        public bool randomPointsColors = false;
        public Bitmap bmpWithPoints;


        public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1;

        public void Init()
        {
            bmpWithoutPoints = new Bitmap(bmpWithPoints.Width, bmpWithPoints.Height);
            bmpnew = new Bitmap(bmpWithPoints.Width, bmpWithPoints.Height);

            if (bmpWithPoints == null)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < bmpWithPoints.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < bmpWithPoints.Height; y++)
                    {
                        bmpWithPoints.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }
                }

                Color c = Color.Red;
                for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
                    {
                        if (randomPointsColors == true)
                        {
                            c = Color.FromArgb(
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c = pointsColor;
                        }
                        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpWithPoints))
                        {
                            //g.FillCircle(Brushes.Red, clouds1[x], 5);
                        }
                        bmpWithPoints.SetPixel(r.Next(0, bmpWithPoints.Width), r.Next(0, bmpWithPoints.Height), c);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                randomPointsColors = false;
            }
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

            ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(bmpWithPoints);//@"c:\temp\anim3.gif");
            mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            //blackImage = ConvertTo24(blackImage);
            //mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            distanceFromCenterPixels = (float)(/*183d*/ ((double)200 / 1.09289617486) * (double)distanceFromCenterKm / 200d);
            argbValuesOfTransparentTexture = new byte[bytes];

            InitializeDirectX(pb1);

            FindPoints();
            //initialize angleArray
            angleArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];
            distanceArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < detectedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                CalculateAngleAndDistance(detectedPoints[i].X, detectedPoints[i].Y, out angleCalculation, out distance);

                angleArray[i] = (float)angleCalculation;
                distanceArray[i] = (float)distance;
            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void GetPictureBox(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1)
        {

        }

        private void FillCircle(Graphics g, Brush brush,
                              PointF center, float radius)
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.FillEllipse(brush, center.X - radius, center.Y - radius,
                                 radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }

        static float angleF_ = 0.0F;
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (angleF_ > 360F)
            {
                angleF_ -= 360F;
            }

            ReturnTexture(scannedCloudsTexture, detectedPoints, angleArray, angleF_, bmpnew);

            DisplayOnScreen(angleF_);

            // To change direction to change += to -=
            // To change speed to raise the value 1.0d 
            angleF_ += 1.0F;
        }

        private Bitmap ConvertTo24(string inputFileName)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(inputFileName);

            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                // Prevent DPI conversion
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                // Draw the image
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            //converted.Save(outputFileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }

        private Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap inputFileName)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Bitmap bmpIn = inputFileName;

            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                // Prevent DPI conversion
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                // Draw the image
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            //converted.Save(outputFileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }

        public static Stream ToStream(Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, formaw);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        public Boolean InitializeDirectX(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1)
        {

            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
                                                              //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                //D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                //load imagesBmp to panelTexture
                //panelTexture = Texture.FromBitmap(D3Ddev, imagesBmp, Usage.Dynamic, Pool.Default)

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);




                //scannerTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\Buttons\Radar\radar.png");
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bmpn;
        float angle = 0;
        private void DisplayOnScreen(float angleF)
        {

            if (angle < 360)
            {
                bmpn = new Bitmap(512, 512);
                angle++;
            }
            else
            {
                angle = 361;
            }
            Surface backbuffer;
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(110, 0, 255, 0)); //semi transparent color to draw the rotating cone 
            Graphics g;

            //clear the backbuffer with Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56). This is the double buffer mechanism. Drawing to offscreen 
            //backbuffer and in the end flipping it to main one which is our panelContainer 
            D3Ddev.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56), 1, 0);
            D3Ddev.BeginScene();

            //Draw Sprites 
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            D3Dsprite.Begin(SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend);

            // bitmap with clouds 
            //D3Dsprite.Draw2D(backTexture, new PointF(0, 0), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //the part of clouds that are inside the cone 
            D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannedCloudsTexture, new PointF(0F, 0F), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //rotate cone 
            //D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannerTexture, new PointF(104.5F, 0F), angle, new PointF(256F, 255F), Color.White); 

            D3Dsprite.Flush();
            D3Dsprite.End();
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


            //Draw the cone. 
            using (backbuffer = D3Ddev.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono))
            {
                using (g = backbuffer.GetGraphics())
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    g.FillPie(myBrush, 256F - distanceFromCenterPixels, 255F - distanceFromCenterPixels,
                    distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, angleF - 23F, 46F);
                    if (angle <= 360)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

            D3Ddev.EndScene();
            D3Ddev.Present(); //performs the flipping 

        }

        private void CalculateAngleAndDistance(int x, int y, out double angle, out double distance)
        {
            Double dbl = -1.0d;
            Point center = new Point(256, 255);

            distance = Math.Sqrt((double)((center.Y - y) * (center.Y - y) + (center.X - x) * (center.X - x)));

            if (y == center.Y && x > center.X)
            {
                dbl = 0d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y > center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 90d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (y == center.Y && x < center.X)
            {
                dbl = 180d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y < center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 279d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y == center.Y)
            {
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }

            if (x > center.X && y > center.Y) //1
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y > center.Y) //2
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 180d - dbl;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y < center.Y) //3
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl += 180d;
            }
            else //4
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 360d - dbl;
            }


            angle = dbl;
        }

        private void ReturnTexture(Texture texture_take, List<Point> lstPnt, float[] anglArr, float angle, Bitmap bmpNew)
        {
            int i, j, stride = 2048;
            float angleBefore, angleAfter;
            GraphicsStream textureStream;
            Boolean bl = false;

            if (bmpNew.Width != 512 && bmpNew.Height != 512)
                throw new Exception("Bitmaps must be of same size.");

            //sets texture to complete transparent 
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* p = argbValuesOfTransparentTexture)
                {
                    MemSet((IntPtr)p, 0x0, argbValuesOfTransparentTexture.Length);
                }
            }


            angleAfter = angle + 23F;

            if (angleAfter >= 360F)
            {
                angleAfter -= 360F;
            }

            angleBefore = angleAfter - 46;

            if (angleBefore < 0F)
            {
                angleBefore += 360F;
                bl = true;
            }

            BitmapData bmD = bmpNew.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)bmD.Scan0.ToPointer();
                //checks all points and draws yellow only those who are inside the cone 
                for (i = 0; i < lstPnt.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (anglArr[i] == -1F)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (bl == true)
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter || anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter && anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            //if (angle <= 360)
            //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");

            bmpNew.UnlockBits(bmD);



            {
                using (textureStream = texture_take.LockRectangle(0, LockFlags.None))
                {
                    textureStream.Write(argbValuesOfTransparentTexture);
                    texture_take.UnlockRectangle(0);
                }

                //if (angle <= 360)
                //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");
            }
        }

        private void FindPoints()
        {


            //Bitmap bmptest;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            int x, y, p, j, wdthHght;
            int bytes;
            //byte error_ = 5;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithClouds;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithoutClouds;
            IntPtr ptr;
            Rectangle rect;
            BitmapData bitmap_Data;

            gp.AddEllipse(new RectangleF(73, 72, 367, 367));

            //gp.CloseFigure();

            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithPoints = new Bitmap(mymem))//@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radartobmp.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithPoints.Width, bmpWithPoints.Height);
                wdthHght = bmpWithPoints.Width;

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithPoints.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithPoints.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithPoints.Height;

                rgbValuesWithClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithPoints.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }


            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithoutPoints = new Bitmap(this.bmpWithoutPoints))
            //@"D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\WithoutClouds.bmp"))//su + "\\WithoutClouds.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithoutPoints.Width, bmpWithoutPoints.Height);

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithoutPoints.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithoutPoints.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithoutPoints.Height;

                rgbValuesWithoutClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithoutClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithoutPoints.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }

            // Each position in these arrays, rgbValuesWithoutClouds and rgbValuesWithClouds, corresponds a color. eg
            // First pixel   Second pixel   Third pixel   Forth pixel .... // bitmaps
            //    B G R          B G R         B G R         B G R    .... // rgbValues arrays
            //bmptest = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            detectedPoints = new List<Point>();

            for (y = 0; y < wdthHght; y++)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (x = 0; x < wdthHght; x++)
                {

                    p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;

                    if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p])
                    {
                        detectedPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                        //bmptest.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    }

                    j += 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i put a break point on the first line in the DopplerEffect class it will not stop on this line either.

But again the test i did in the form1 constructor show that something is wrong with the DopplerEffect class.

Comment: That sounds strange. I agree, the problem seems to be in the class DopplerEffect, but I have no idea why. The class has no constructor defined and the initialization of fields looks quite normal. I have only one hint: I am not experienced in DirectX. Did you use this assemblies in other projects before? One reason the constructor is not reached is when type initialization fails and I am not sure whether you will see this in Visual Studio output or not. Especially when using also native DLLs.

Comment: The strange thing is that the same class is working on my older project a big project without a problem. And in this project it's the third project i started over created and it's not working.

Comment: And it's not throwing any exceptions. Maybe i should enable some/any exception in he exceptions settings ?

Comment: Enable Exception may help, but I don't think so as far as there is no exception in debug output. Are there differences between this project and the (working) older ones? Other DirectX references, other .NET Framework Version etc. I still suspect, it has something to do with external references.

Comment: Here is a link to the project the rar file include the directx dll files in the directory: Bin > Debug or Bin > x86 > Debug

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=10919664595589925254

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen i will keep looking for some differences in the projects. So far i didn't find something that will solve it.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I am one step further. I took your code and find out, that the problem has to do with `DisplayMode`. I found, that it is declared as an instance varialbe, but used only in one method. So I made the following changes. I removed the instance variable: 
`       private PresentParameters D3Dpp = null;
        //private DisplayMode DispMode;
        private Sprite D3Dsprite = null;
`
and defined it inside the method:
`DisplayMode DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;`

Comment: This way the program starts, but "hang" when `InitializeDirectX` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple, but Visual Studio make it not always easy to find.

If you check "Enable native code debugging" in your project properties, Debug page and run your program, you will get an exception "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

Short research leads to [Managed DirectX running from .Net Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751179/managed-directx-running-from-net-framework-4-0-app-dont-hunt).

Change your app.cofig to

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
```

and it will run.

Comment: Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoaderLock' has detected a problem in 'D:\C-Sharp\DopplerRadarEffect\DopplerRadarEffect\DopplerRadarEffect\bin\x86\Release\DopplerRadarEffect.exe'.

Additional information: DLL 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: It's working but when i'm running the program i'm getting another exception message and then when i click the continue button it will work fine. I just wonder if the exception message is important and i should handle it ? Or i should uncheck now back the "Enable native code debugging" and ignore the exception ? ( The exception message in my first comment above this one ).

Comment: Ok i found how to work around this. It's not a solution but if i go to the Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and there to Managed Debugging Assistants and then unchecked the LoaderLock so now when running the program i'm not getting any exceptions and it's working fine. But again this is not a solution for the exception.

Comment: I am afraid that **is** the solution as long as the application runs as expected. You could search for "DirectX" and this Exception and you will find out, that obviously the initialization code of DirectX causes the exception.