# Visual Studio debugging run ignores stepping and breakpoints and executes indefinitely

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, upgrade

I have been struggling with a weird issue in Visual Studio 2017 for some time and cannot find any information about it anywhere.

I am currently in the process of refactoring and upgrading a large legacy application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6.1. It executes perfectly in .NET 3.5, but throws an error when executed with .NET 4.0 or newer as the target framework without the debugger.

To debug this, I run the program in debug mode through Visual Studio. When running in debug mode, stepping and breakpoints are ignored after reaching a certain class, despite the Diagnostic Tool showing program activity.

### [Diagnostic Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeaoI.png)

The problem goes away if the class in question, which is called MainMenuForm (and has far too many responsibilities) is not called. It does not matter if I call static fields in the non-static MainMenuForm class or if I call the constructor.

I suspect the problem to be related to the JIT compiler finding something odd, but would expect an exception to be thrown or an error of some sort.

Has anyone encountered similar issues when upgrading to a newer version?

Comment: Assuming the application consists of many assemblies, are all assemblies targeting the same framework and set to run in Debug as the target?

Comment: Make sure you have uninstalled and cleaned previous build. This behavior often means that the DLL being used is not the one you just compiled but another one (a simple new message box will confirm it).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. 

All the 19 projects are targetting the same framework and are set to run in debug.

There are however some third party dependencies that are used in the perpetrator class file. I thought .NET was backwards compatible, and that this would not pose a problem. But I will try to see what happens if I eliminate the third party dependencies one by one.

I have tried to clean the solution and also manually delete bin and obj folders, but this did not help

Comment: @Excavator, you said that you update this app form .net 3.5, does it mean that this project was created in old VS version? If so, do you get any warning or error during you open it in VS2017? Not debug your app, whether you get any compiled error if you just build it or run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)"? It has 19 projects in your solution, whether it is related to the specific project? If it has no error during you run it using "start without debugging", please enable the Exception settings under debug menu, and debug it again.

Comment: Good questions. The projects were created in Visual Studio 2008, but works perfectly in Visual Studio 2017 when framework is set to 3.5 or older. In addition to migrating the old solution, I also created a new one and pasted in all the source code. This did not change anything, so the migration tool is apparently pretty effective. The application runs perfectly through VS2017 both with and without debugger in 3.5, but throws an error without the debugger and gets stuck with the debugger in 4.0 and above. All code relevant to the problem is in one project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Following input from Snympi and JGH, I started looking into the dependencies for the problem class. It turns out that it had a legacy DirectX dependency which apparently is handled differently by the CLR 4.0.

The answer to this post solved the issue:
[Managed DirectX running from .Net Framework 4.0 app dont hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751179/managed-directx-running-from-net-framework-4-0-app-dont-hunt)

Adding the below to App.config made the debugger be able to step through the program.

`<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>`

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if so, you could mark it as the answer:)